# How is 멘탈 잡아 used?

Tags: meaning, spoken-korean

I was watching this show, and the situation starts at 7:06.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5gowWjwlm10&t=555s

I understand that they're embarassed but I don't get the nuance of this expression...
Also how can it be used in other circumstances?
Could you tell me a few examples of how is 멘탈 잡아 used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t have enough English vocabulary to pick up the best translation from; bear with me about that.

The slang “멘탈,” which is the Korean transcription of the English word “mental,” translates to “**mind**,” and “잡아” (“잡다” + “-아”) to imperative “**Hold**.” It basically means “Get your mind back” or “Don’t lose your mind.” You say this to someone when he’s going crazy or his mind is getting numb or distracted for whatever reason. Depending on the context, it could also mean “Chill out,” “Wake up,” “Be sane,” “Don’t panic,” or “Don’t cringe out.”

Answer (score 2):

멘탈 잡아 is used in following situations

Your firm colleague: 나 프로젝트 때문에 제정신이 아닌거 같아(I think I am beside my self because of project)
you: (you can say) 멘탈잡아!(it is hard to transform 멘탈잡아 to English, but I think it is similar meaning with “concentrate!”

Friend A: 여기서 뭔일이 일어나고있는거야 (what is going on here) (situation that your friend is very confused about here)
Friend B:  제발 침착하고 멘탈잡아(Please be calm and keep your head)

I hope you understand this.^^